# Problems Deploy Webservices in oracle Weblogic 10.01

Tags: java, oracle10g, weblogic

i am using jwsc to build my webservices application. This produces a war file with a weblogic.xml like the following:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.0/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
      <context-root>eori-ws</context-root>
    </weblogic-web-app>
```

As you can see the namespace points towards bea.com. When i try to deploy the war (inside an ear) to my weblogic i get the following:

```
        An error occurred during activation of changes, please see the log for details.
            [HTTP:101064][WebAppModule(eori_services:eori-ws)] Error parsing descriptor in Web appplication 
"/softs/apps/bea1001/user_projects/domains/myapp/servers/myServer/tmp/_WL_user/myapp/jd3urj/myapp-ws.war" 
weblogic.application.ModuleException: Unmarshaller failed at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.loadDescriptor(WebAppModule.java:858) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:285) 

   (snip)
   weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:464) 
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:200) at 
weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:172) Caused by: 
com.bea.xml.XmlException: failed to load java type corresponding to e=weblogic-web-app@http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app  at 
com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.getPojoBindingType(UnmarshalResult.java:329) 
at 
com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.determineTypeForGlobalElement(UnmarshalResult.java:296) 
at 

    (snip)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppDescriptor.getWeblogicWebAppBean(WebAppDescriptor.java:164) 
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.loadDescriptor(WebAppModule.java:853) 
... 25 more weblogic.application.ModuleException: Unmarshaller failed
    Failed to load java type corresponding to e=weblogic-web-app@http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
```

i've tried changing the url to match the new domain and i get the same error. I've tried downloading the xsd and putting it in the same folder of the weblogic.xml, wich i changed to look like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="weblogic-web-app.xsd">
  <context-root>eori-ws</context-root>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

and the error is still the same

I'm out of ideas. Any help?

EDIT: no solution yet, ill post solution when i find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. Seems i was using the wrong version of the JWSC ant task. Just make sure to use the correct weblogic.jar